# Unset specific css files defined in the .info file

Tags: theming, .info

I am trying to unset specific CSS files that I have included in the .info file in specific languages. For example, I have Arabic as a language option in my website, and I am including the ar.css file with:

```
drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('theme', 'ninesixty') . "/styles/framework/ar.css");
drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('theme', 'ninesixty') . "/styles/framework/rtl_960_24.css");
```

I have to remove the 960.css and 960_24.css files from the Arabic language as those files define the left to right text direction. 
I am trying this using these two lines, without success:

```
unset($vars['css']['all']['module']['styles/framework/960_24.css']);
unset($vars['css']['all']['module']['styles/framework/960.css']);
```

In order to understand when the user is using Arabic (for the front page, firstly) I am using the following code:

```
if ($vars['is_front']) {
  $langcode = $GLOBALS['language']-> language;
  if ($langcode == 'ar' || $langcode == "fa") {
    drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('theme', 'ninesixty') . "/styles/framework/ar.css");
    drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('theme', 'ninesixty') . "/styles/framework/rtl_960_24.css");
    unset($vars['css']['all']['module']['styles/framework/960_24.css']);
    unset($vars['css']['all']['module']['styles/framework/960.css']);
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you using Drupal 7?

Comment: Why are you unsetting the CSS? you can just a rule in the css that sets left-to-right or right-to-left depending on the language code of the document ... you should have a language value in your [HTML header](http://fortysevenmedia.com/blog/archives/styling_right-to-left_text_with_css_on_a_multi-lingual_site/) you can go off of. My D7 does with an [Adaptive Theme](http://drupal.org/project/adaptivetheme) subtheme

Comment: ok. its fixed. I just removed the unset lines and the arabic website started to looks better.:) Thanks